# SoftLayer CLI - Unable to retrieve image -UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

While initiating VSI request through CLI, we are not receiving the image list.

We are getting the following error:

> From slcli image list > images
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: We were able to modify our script to filter out images that causing the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the python client I recomend you to submit the issue to the github project https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues

Regards